Extend the domain of a sobol sequence, while having same value on initial domain
I have an algorithm that can generate a Sobol sequence of length n for ndim dimensions, and in a given domain. For example, I can can draw n=45 points, with ndim=2 dimensions, in the range [0.9, 1.1] for the first dimension and [0.25, 0.29] for the second one. It gives me the following values: https://i.sstatic.net/9411H.png
Now, I would like to find a way to extend the ranges (let say [0.8, 1.2] for the 1st dimension and [0.24, 0.3] for the 2nd one), and having the new points overlapping with the ones obtained on the previous range, like this: https://i.sstatic.net/nm2X5.png
Is there a way to what should be the length of the sequence n to obtain this result ?
In practice, it could be slightly more flexible. The user could say: "i want to extend this sequence with n = 100 and ranges = [0.8, 1.2] and [0.24, 0.3], and recover previous points", and the algorithm could say "ok, this can be achieved with n = 102 and ranges = [0.796, 1.193] and [0.2402, 0.304]. Do you want to proceed ? [Y]/n"
Thanks !
